# routes generated with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

When I try to generate one route as shown on Rails documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), such as:

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'
```

the route I generate doesn't have any prefix, i.e. I cannot create a link to that page, for example:

```
link_to "patient profile", prefix_path(patient)
```

However when I use resource routing, which generates all the routes at once, the routes created all have a prefix.

```
resources :patients
```

> Why can I not get a prefix with the first method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails creates all url helpers automatically every time you use `resources`, but for custom routes, you need to specify it yourself using `as`, for example:

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient_show'
```

And to use it:

```
<%= link_to "patient profile", patient_show_path(patient) %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I thought as was only there to change the default prefix, not to entirely create one when missing! For anyone else reading this: as needs to be followed by a colon like so as: 'patient_show'

Comment: @Lauraponi Glad to help! And thanks for catching the missing colon!